# Why does AddressBookSourceSync request connections to myriad different servers?

Tags: macos

I've recently installed a new version of Little Snitch, and it informs me that the process **AddressBookSourceSync** wants to contact a server. I understand the process is for syncing Contacts. What I don't understand is why it should be connecting to servers such as:

- cnet.com
- fda.gov

and a raft of others that seem to bear no relation to my contacts (no one in my contacts has email addresses or anything else relating to CNet of the FDA).

Is this process doing more than just syncing contacts?

I'm running 10.8.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't actually connecting to those sites it is connecting to Akamai server that host content for several sites. If you click on the "Show details button" You'll see that the reverse DNS name is for an Akamai server.

Comment: Thanks, @dan. That makes sense. I can't get it to initiate any connections at the moment, so I'll have to take your word for it! Thanks for answering!